# Preview size automatically changed to 1024X768 in galaxy tab which has 1200X800 surface view

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, javacv

I want to show a video preview in my galaxy tab which has surface view of 1200X800 when I try to set the camera parameters with that value, it just does not take, if it does not take, it shows me squeezed videos. After finding the issue, I found that, it takes the resolution of 1024X768, I am not sure why its not taking it.

Code for Camera

```
class CameraView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, PreviewCallback {

    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private Camera.Size previewSize;
    private List<Camera.Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;

    public CameraView(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        Log.w("camera", "camera view");
        mCamera = camera;
        mSupportedPreviewSizes =  mCamera.getParameters(). getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(CameraView.this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(CameraView.this);

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            stopPreview();
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

        } catch (IOException exception) {
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        stopPreview();

        Camera.Parameters camParams = mCamera.getParameters();
        List<Camera.Size> sizes = camParams.getSupportedPictureSizes();
        camParams.setPictureSize(sizes.get(0).width, sizes.get(0).height);
        List<Camera.Size> size = camParams.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        // Sort the list in ascending order
        Collections.sort(size, new Comparator<Camera.Size>() {

            public int compare(final Camera.Size a, final Camera.Size b) {
                return a.width * a.height - b.width * b.height;
            }
        });

        // Pick the first preview size that is equal or bigger, or pick the last (biggest) option if we cannot
        // reach the initial settings of imageWidth/imageHeight.
        for (int i = 0; i < size.size(); i++) {
            if ((size.get(i).width >= imageWidth && sizes.get(i).height >= imageHeight) || i == size.size() - 1) {
                imageWidth = size.get(i).width;
                imageHeight = size.get(i).height;
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Changed to supported resolution: " + imageWidth + "x" + imageHeight);
                break;
            }
        }
        camParams.setPreviewSize(imageWidth, imageHeight);

        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Setting imageWidth: " + imageWidth + " imageHeight: " + imageHeight + " frameRate: " + frameRate);

        camParams.setPreviewFrameRate(frameRate);
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Preview Framerate: " + camParams.getPreviewFrameRate());

        mCamera.setParameters(camParams);

        // Set the holder (which might have changed) again
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(CameraView.this);
            startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Could not set preview display in surfaceChanged");
        }


    }

    private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
        double targetRatio = (double) h / w;

        if (sizes == null)
            return null;

        Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        int targetHeight = h;

        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
            double ratio = (double) size.height / size.width;
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE)
                continue;

            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }

        if (optimalSize == null) {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }

        return optimalSize;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
        final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, width +  " and " + height);

        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

        if (previewSize != null) {
            previewSize =
                    getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            mHolder.addCallback(null);
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            // The camera has probably just been released, ignore.
        }
    }

    public void startPreview() {
        if (!isPreviewOn && mCamera != null) {
            isPreviewOn = true;
            mCamera.startPreview();
        }
    }

    public void stopPreview() {
        if (isPreviewOn && mCamera != null) {
            isPreviewOn = false;
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        if (audioRecord == null || audioRecord.getRecordingState() != AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_RECORDING) {
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            return;
        }
        if (RECORD_LENGTH > 0) {
            int i = imagesIndex++ % images.length;
            yuvImage = images[i];
            timestamps[i] = 1000 * (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
        }
        /* get video data */
        if (yuvImage != null && recording) {
            ((ByteBuffer)yuvImage.image[0].position(0)).put(data);

            if (RECORD_LENGTH <= 0) try {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Writing Frame");
                long t = 1000 * (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
                if (t > recorder.getTimestamp()) {
                    recorder.setTimestamp(t);
                }
                recorder.record(yuvImage);
            } catch (FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception e) {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried with getOptimalPreviewSize however, id did not work either.

Comment: if I use the code for getOptimalPreviewSize() then it returns, 1024X576

Comment: is not there anyone who can answer this question?

Comment: This camera doesn't support preview resolution of 1200×800. You should use whatever getOptimalPreviewSize()  returns, and the image will be slightly upscaled. If you see a distorted preview, you may need to resize the surface view so that it's aspect ratio is precisely same as the chosen preview.